# Java: can´t get ObjectInputStream from socket

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am doing java server client application and I have got problem. I succesfully get client´s socket, bud when I wanna make ObjectInputStream it stuck.

Code:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);

while(true){
    System.out.println("Waiting for player");
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Player connected, waiting for command");

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("input created");      
}
```

Output:
`Waiting for player
Player connected, waiting for command`

What can I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ObjectInputStream` waits for an incoming header. Until the header is completly received you will be stuck at this line:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

to solve this problem you need to invoke `flush()` on the ObjectOutputStream on the other side (i.e. the server) as soon as the connection is established.

For more information read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28%29).

Comment: it is not working for me .